# Can VS Code and Jupyter Lab share the same virtual environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

At work I have both Jupyter Lab and VS Code installed. Jupyter Lab is supported by our IT and I have been able to use pip to install the packages I am using to learn and develop with. I am unable to do the same with VS Code without elevated (admin) rights. Can I simply point my VS Code environment to point to the packages already installed? I want to use VS Code for development to leverage it's debugging capability, etc.

Can someone point me to resources to help me configure my VS Code environment without having to coerce IT to do pip installs for me with their admin rights?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using for your environments? _Can someone point me to resources..._ Have you done any research already?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into installing Anaconda, which includes Jupyter Lab and its own virtual environment. Then you can simply select which virtual environment you want to use.

Select and click Python on down left conner and select appropriate virtenv

[image]

Comment: 1. I have miniconda installed, have set up a virtual envirmonment rgvenv, and have installed modules to that rgvenv, which I have successfully imported and used via jupyter lab.
2. I selected the Python 3.7.3 located at C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe.
3. a simple program like: import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'J:\shrproj\PrimeMail Programs\JobTracker\JobsByMonth\ActiveJobs_2019M10.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print(df)

Comment: … produced the below error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\Users\pta67589\vscode\.vscode\Untitled-1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'